# Error message in terminal when trying to generate bundle in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am at the start of learning Symfony 2, and to be fair, this question is likely to seem very basic. I am having trouble just getting started - I suspect there is a configuration issue either with my Symfony project or my configuration in PHP. When I type php app/console, this is the error I am getting. I don't seem to be able to do anything, such as generate bundles. If someone could at least give me some direction on where to start with this error I would be grateful. I am a rookie.

```
    unknown-ec:35:86:4d:41:5e:symfonyTest simonalice$ php app/console
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-     non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-  20090626/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug- non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysqli.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0



    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
    Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or  
   the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for 'BST/1.0/DST' instead in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonyTest/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php line 233
```

Looking at my phpini() file....

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; Note that it should be the name of the module only; no directory information 
; needs to go here.  Specify the location of the extension with the
; extension_dir directive above.


; Extensions

extension=apcu.so
extension=imap.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

;extension=imagick.so
;extension=tidy.so
```

And yet with this set up I am still getting the error message in when I input php app/console

Driving me nuts at this point.....

Comment: I edited my answer try to use that configuration .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check your php.ini file for any uncommented lines like extension= under Dynamic Extensions section .
`extension=php_mysql.dll`
an active extension should not begin with ';'

try to add these lines

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

PS: im not a Mac user but this can help you [forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=4886](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=4886)

Comment: @GhostRider try to add these lines

Comment: In fact, I looked in /private/etc/php.ini and found that those lines were present and uncommented out. I commented them out and the error disappeared. Now this is what I don't understand - if my phpinfo() file says that my phpini() path is /Library/ApplicationSupport/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini, then why in God's name would altering the phpini file in private/etc/php.ini have any impact? Error gone, but don't understand why which is not satisfying......

Comment: im not a Mac user but this can help you http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=4886

Comment: Many thanks...this solved this problem. If you post as an answer I can mark it.